# How can i install Python interpreter in PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I had the possibility to install Python interpreters in PyCharm.
I installed 3.8 Anaconda and others, using them with virtual environments on my projects as we can see here:

[image: Run/Debug Configurations]

For some reason i can not see and change/add new interpreters anymore:

[image: Settings/Python interpreters]

I already deinstalled PyCharm 2021.2 and installed PyCharm 2021.3, but still the same issue. Whats going wrong?

Comment: have you checked the Jetbrains documentation [Configure a Conda virtual environment](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/conda-support-creating-conda-virtual-environment.html#1e4b9b23)

Comment: @chickitychinachinesechicken yes, i have. but that documentation is not helpful, as it does not cover the case when i have no possibility to add/select an interpreter which is already known to PyCharm, somehow... as you can see in my question.